# Requesting staking accounts

Tags: web3.js, staking

I requesting staked accounts with this request

```
return (
      await this.connectionService
        .getBalanceConnection()
        .getProgramAccounts(STAKE_PROGRAM_ID, filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 200, // number of bytes
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 44, // number of bytes
            bytes: walletAddress, // base58 encoded string
          },
        },
      ],)
```

And now I receive Internal Servier Error, but sometimes before all works. Maybe exists other way to request staking accounts? Or maybe something I am doing wrong.

Error:

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"12f9dbff-aaae-428e-444-ab5ff56854c9","error":{"code":-32603,"message":"Internal server error"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most RPC providers restrict calling `getProgramAccounts`, so likely the RPC node is throttling you.  If you're using this call often and running into issues, you may need to get your own node.